# aws "eb create" fails - CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, wagtail

I want to deploy [this wagtail app](https://github.com/Dolidodzik/Ketowataha.pl) on aws elasic beanstalk. I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) (tutorial from aws docs gave similiar output). After running `eb create`, I get errors, see below. I would appreciate any help/letting me know how can I fix that issue, fell free to ask about more details. Thank you. Tracebacks/outputs are below.

Full CLI output of command:

```
$ eb create
Enter Environment Name
(default is KetoWatahapl-dev):
Enter DNS CNAME prefix
(default is KetoWatahapl-dev2):

Select a load balancer type
1) classic
2) application
3) network
(default is 2):

Would you like to enable Spot Fleet requests for this environment?
(y/N):
Creating application version archive "app-59f08-200204_165232".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
An environment with that name already exists.
Enter Environment Name
(default is KetoWatahapl-dev2):
Environment details for: KetoWatahapl-dev2
  Application name: KetoWataha.pl
  Region: eu-west-2
  Deployed Version: app-59f08-200204_165232
  Environment ID: e-d2bhkaxyjb
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.5
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: KetoWatahapl-dev2.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2020-02-04 16:53:59.028000+00:00
Printing Status:
2020-02-04 16:53:57    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2020-02-04 16:53:59    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-2-937659118370 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2020-02-04 16:54:19    INFO    Created target group named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:937659118370:targetgroup/awseb-AWSEB-11WD0ELT384UU/3b39ac8f6d0588e2
2020-02-04 16:54:19    INFO    Created security group named: sg-0f6f6ff7efea6a00f
2020-02-04 16:54:35    INFO    Created security group named: awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-SLG8B3C63Q4Q
2020-02-04 16:54:35    INFO    Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-MNBVA4OJIYOB
2020-02-04 16:55:52    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-7CFA9HIAH7FH
2020-02-04 16:55:52    INFO    Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
2020-02-04 16:55:52    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-2:937659118370:scalingPolicy:ff32d1ea-8883-482d-b9bd-e515c141dbde:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-7CFA9HIAH7FH:policyName/awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-C212M7GFNU3M
2020-02-04 16:55:52    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-2:937659118370:scalingPolicy:306d9044-84e9-4742-a020-51ce96369e60:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-7CFA9HIAH7FH:policyName/awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-FJVHSMPMLCEY
2020-02-04 16:56:07    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-VEF331G78RF0
2020-02-04 16:56:07    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-d2bhkaxyjb-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-162SDJGCXB14F
2020-02-04 16:56:55    INFO    Created load balancer named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:937659118370:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-U4P02MJ5WUS0/08dce9dbc26658fe
2020-02-04 16:56:55    INFO    Created Load Balancer listener named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:937659118370:listener/app/awseb-AWSEB-U4P02MJ5WUS0/08dce9dbc26658fe/b57c8b8a3384f6df
2020-02-04 16:57:08    ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
2020-02-04 16:57:10    ERROR   [Instance: i-0174274ab20e1cab8] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2020-02-04 16:57:10    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-02-04 16:58:13    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

Also I couldn't find log here:

```
dolidod@debian:/var/log$ pwd
/var/log
dolidod@debian:/var/log$ ls
alternatives.log       daemon.log.3.gz  kern.log           syslog.1
alternatives.log.1     daemon.log.4.gz  kern.log.1         syslog.2.gz
alternatives.log.2.gz  debug            kern.log.2.gz      syslog.3.gz
alternatives.log.3.gz  debug.1          kern.log.3.gz      syslog.4.gz
alternatives.log.4.gz  debug.2.gz       kern.log.4.gz      syslog.5.gz
alternatives.log.5.gz  debug.3.gz       lastlog            syslog.6.gz
alternatives.log.6.gz  debug.4.gz       libvirt            syslog.7.gz
apt                    dpkg.log         lightdm            unattended-upgrades
aptitude               dpkg.log.1       lxdm.log           user.log
aptitude.1.gz          dpkg.log.2.gz    lxdm.log.1         user.log.1
auth.log               dpkg.log.3.gz    lxdm.log.old       user.log.2.gz
auth.log.1             dpkg.log.4.gz    messages           user.log.3.gz
auth.log.2.gz          dpkg.log.5.gz    messages.1         user.log.4.gz
auth.log.3.gz          dpkg.log.6.gz    messages.2.gz      vbox-setup.log
auth.log.4.gz          dpkg.log.7.gz    messages.3.gz      vbox-setup.log.1
boot.log               exim4            messages.4.gz      vbox-setup.log.2
btmp                   faillog          mysql              wtmp
btmp.1                 firebird         nginx              Xorg.0.log
cups                   fontconfig.log   private            Xorg.0.log.old
daemon.log             gdm3             sddm.log
daemon.log.1           hp               speech-dispatcher
daemon.log.2.gz        installer        syslog
```

Comment: `eb logs` using the CLI will download the logs.

Comment: Also try `eb create --verbose` to see if more stuff gets printed.

Comment: I have no idea about what you want but this error I got before when i tried to install MySQL into the Django project and that happened because the project was missing the file called requirements.txt and I think that is what is going on here with you. this is just what i guess

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin I just want to simply deploy django/wagtail app on aws EB, I tried couple of ways to do it. Thank you for your help, I'll try to do it.

Comment: @DolidodTeethtard actually if you read the tutorial on Real Python that you linked, you'll see [here](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#configure-eb-create-an-environment) that this error is expected. As written there, you should look at the logs with `eb logs` and you'll see what caused the error. The tutorial says it's probably the missing postgreSQL client drivers (`Error: pg_config executable not found.`)